# Linear mixed effect model; degrees of freedom preventing interaction effect?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have the following head of data

```
   P.1              P. 2             ID      type host
1        1.7256480 0.40104059         CA      B ZE
2        0.3890683 0.09030274         CA      C ZE
3        0.7391744 0.17082319         CA      B AC
4        0.5805214 0.07082361         CA      C AC
5        0.4078236 0.04742988         CAM     B AC
6        0.3366595 0.08776712         CAM     C AC
7        0.4990650 0.08534011         CAM     B AC
8        0.4011365 0.10477684         CAM     C  AC
```

the dose is unbalanced within  ID, but the type is balanced

I am running this model

`lmer(P.1 ~ ID + (type * host), + (1|room), data)`

However, in my output table, the interaction between ID and type does not appear. Looking into it (removing the host interaction) I see it takes 4 degrees of freedom. I know DOF and linear mixed-effects models are tricky, but I don't know why the interaction won't show up. For reference, I have 5 levels of ID with varying levels of type and host within each level of ID. I'm going to guess the variation can't be partitioned, but I want to know why, if anyone has an idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would the interaction between ID and type appear in your model summary if it is not included in your model formula?

The model as you currently have it:

```
lmer(P.1 ~ ID + type * host + (1|room), data)
```

allows only for a two-way interaction between type and host; it does not allow for any other interactions.

If you wanted your model to also include a two-way interaction between type and ID, one way to specify that would be like this:

```
lmer(P.1 ~ ID + type + host + ID:type + type:host + (1|room), data)
```

or, equivalently:

```
lmer(P.1 ~ (ID + host)*type + (1|room), data)
```

If you wanted your model to include all possible two-way interactions between ID, type and host, then you could specify it like this:

```
lmer(P.1 ~ ID + type + host + ID:type + ID:host + type:host + (1|room), data)
```

or, equivalently, like this:

```
lmer(P.1 ~ (ID + type + host)^2 + (1|room), data)
```

If you wanted your model to include all possible two-way interactions between ID, type and host as well as their three-way interaction, then you could specify it like this:

```
lmer(P.1 ~ ID + type + host + ID:type + ID:host + type:host + ID:type:host + (1|room), data)
```

or like this (short form):

```
lmer(P.1 ~ ID*type*host + (1|room), data)
```

Comment: oh wow, of course, how silly. I always thought that the way in which I wrote it was equivalent to a three way interaction, my mistake. Thank you!